# WYGWAM "re-draw" lines in Chrome

Tags: add-on, wygwam

One of my clients is having major "re-draw" issues with WYGWAM while using Chrome (Mac):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8l4D.png

The only way to temporarily lose the lines is to keep resizing the text area. Does anyone know a more permanent solution or reason why it's happening?

We're using EE 2.5.2 and WYGWAM 2.6.3.

EDIT: Just wanted to note that this is fixed in the latest version of Chrome (24.0.1312.52).

Comment: That looks suspiciously like an underwhelming video card. Do you know what sort of system they're using? In particular the graphic card. Does it occur in other browsers as well ?

Comment: I see similar behavior in Chrome for Windows on my gaming PC (which has a Radeon 6850) and on my 5-year-old iMac. I don't see the same lines when using Safari.

Comment: Well, that sort of points the bone @ chrome for some weird reason.

Comment: Is this happening on freshly opened tabs or ones that have been open for awhile?

Comment: When I tested, it was on freshly opened tabs.

Comment: Are you seeing this happen on the CKeditor demo: http://ckeditor.com/demo ?

Comment: Yes, if I load that page and scroll within the editor with the mouse wheel, I see those lines while using Chrome. As soon as I click the cursor inside the textarea, the lines mostly disappear. I'm not sure if my client has the exact same experience with the lines going away.

Comment: Can you confirm with your client?  I'm not able to reproduce this on the CKEditor demo, but I'll submit a bug report using your screenshot.

Comment: I get this too; it seems to be specific to Chrome: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=143354 http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=140447 Possible workarounds: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12021248/chrome-bug-iframe-rendering-lines-on-screen-when-scrolling-up

Comment: If you read that Stackoverflow thread, it seems the issue was fixed in Chrome 25.0.1365.1 canary, so it should be going out to stable release soon.

Comment: Wow, that's a long list of potential fixes. But that's why I love Stackoverflow.

Comment: This consistently happens to me as well. It's occurring on a site I upgraded this week to 2.5.5 and the latest Wygwam. I do not have a custom CSS file set for Wygwam either. I'm using a late 2011 11" MacBook Air, latest version of Chrome.

Answer (score 3):

This is a Chrome/Iframe/contentEditable bug that usually crops up when you set Wygwam to use your own CSS file.

You should be able to fix it by adding a line-height to your CSS.

(See https://getsatisfaction.com/pixelandtonic/topics/display_bug_showing_lines_across_editor_when_there_is_lots_of_content#reply_10264807)

Comment: Thanks Brandon. For what it's worth, I'm **not** using my own CSS with Wygwam.